# How to select tuples that doesn't match two criterias in the same query?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Let's supose I have the following table `list_level`

```
| year | cat_id | user_id |  id  | val_1 | val_2  |
|------|--------|---------|------|-------|--------|
| 2017 |      2 |  141256 | 1501 | ABC   | <null> |
| 2017 |      2 |  141256 | 1023 | DRF   | <null> |
| 2017 |      1 |  141256 |  882 | TGV   | 100    |
| 2016 |      2 |  141256 |  801 | ADG   | 90     |
| 2016 |      1 |  141256 |  590 | IKM   | 100    |
| 2016 |      1 |  141256 |  480 | EGM   | 87     |
| 2015 |      2 |  141256 |  256 | YHX   | 70     |
| 2015 |      1 |  141256 |  132 | QWE   | 68     |
```

How do I get the tuples NOT in year = 2017 and NOT in cat_id = 2

I tried

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  LIST_LEVEL
WHERE
 YEAR <> '2017'
 AND CAT_ID NOT IN (2)
```

But that query returns

```
| year | cat_id | user_id |  id  | val_1 | val_2  |
|------|--------|---------|------|-------|--------|
| 2016 |      1 |  141256 |  590 | IKM   | 100    |
| 2016 |      1 |  141256 |  480 | EGM   | 87     |
| 2015 |      1 |  141256 |  132 | QWE   | 68     |
```

And I need this result set

```
| year | cat_id | user_id |  id  | val_1 | val_2  |
|------|--------|---------|------|-------|--------|
| 2017 |      1 |  141256 |  882 | TGV   | 100    |
| 2016 |      2 |  141256 |  801 | ADG   | 90     |
| 2016 |      1 |  141256 |  590 | IKM   | 100    |
| 2016 |      1 |  141256 |  480 | EGM   | 87     |
| 2015 |      2 |  141256 |  256 | YHX   | 70     |
| 2015 |      1 |  141256 |  132 | QWE   | 68     |
```

Finally, I ended whith this query but I think it is a bit complex.

```
SELECT 
  *
FROM (
    SELECT
      *
    FROM
      LIST_LEVEL
    WHERE
      YEAR <> '2017'
    UNION
    SELECT
      *
    FROM
      LIST_LEVEL
    WHERE
      CAT_ID NOT IN (2) 
) T
```

Is there any other way I can write this query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you just want `or`:

```
SELECT ll.*
FROM LIST_LEVEL ll
WHERE ll.YEAR <> '2017' OR CAT_ID NOT IN (2) ;
```

Or, if you prefer:

```
WHERE NOT (ll.YEAR = '2017' AND CAT_ID IN (2) ) ;
```

Comment: Interesting. I'd never have thought in the second option.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  LIST_LEVEL
WHERE
 YEAR <> '2017'
 AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM
 LIST_LEVEL
WHERE CAT_ID IN(2)
```